# Dimension problem when plotting diffusion equation

Tags: python, plot

I reposted this question because I made a mistake with my first post.
I am working on a diffusion equation. However, when I try to plot it, I am getting an error message related to the equality of the dimensions

```
x and y must have same first dimension, but have shapes (401,) and (2001, 401)
```

The x-axis should give the position of particles, while the y-axis should give the number of particles at a given position. I am not sure how to make dimensions equal in this case.

My codes:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

D = 0.5
M = 2000
L = 200
tmax = 2000
dx = 1
dt = 1
s = D*dt/dx**2 #diffusion number
nx = int(2*L/dx)
nt = int(tmax/dt)
nx = nx + 1
nt = nt + 1
x = np.linspace(-L,L,nx)
t = np.linspace(0,tmax,not)

def InitCond(x, M):
    if x == -50:
        c0 = M
    elif x == 50:
        c0 = M
    else:
        c0 = 0
    return c0

def LeftEnd(t):
    return 0

def RightEnd(t):
    return 0

def DiffusionSolver(x,t,s,L,c0,left,right):
    nt = np.size(t)
    nx = np.size(x)
    u = np.zeros((nt,nx))
    # Use the initial condition to define values of 'u' at the 
#zeroeth timestep:
    for j in range(nx):
        u[0,j] = c0(x[j], M)
    # Use the boundary condition to fix the string on its ends:
    u[:,-L] = left(t)
    u[:,L] = right(t)
# Entering the double loop to calculate the solution at every space 
#point at every timestep:
    for k in range(0,nt-1):
        for j in range(1,nx-1):
            u[k+1,j] = s*(u[k,j+1] + u[k,j-1]) + (1 - 2*s)*u[k,j]
    return u
u_num = DiffusionSolver(x,t,s,L,InitCond,LeftEnd,RightEnd)
plt.plot(x, u_num)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to Transform the u_num array so that it's the right shape. Like this:

```css
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

D = 0.5
M = 2000
L = 200
tmax = 2000
dx = 1
dt = 1
s = D*dt/dx**2 #diffusion number
nx = int(2*L/dx)
nt = int(tmax/dt)
nx = nx + 1
nt = nt + 1
x = np.linspace(-L,L,nx)
t = np.linspace(0,tmax,nt)

def InitCond(x, M):
    if x == -50:
        c0 = M
    elif x == 50:
        c0 = M
    else:
        c0 = 0
    return c0

def LeftEnd(t):
    return 0

def RightEnd(t):
    return 0

def DiffusionSolver(x,t,s,L,c0,left,right):
    nt = np.size(t)
    nx = np.size(x)
    u = np.zeros((nt,nx))
    # Use the initial condition to define values of 'u' at the 
#zeroeth timestep:
    for j in range(nx):
        u[0,j] = c0(x[j], M)
    # Use the boundary condition to fix the string on its ends:
    u[:,-L] = left(t)
    u[:,L] = right(t)
# Entering the double loop to calculate the solution at every space 
#point at every timestep:
    for k in range(0,nt-1):
        for j in range(1,nx-1):
            u[k+1,j] = s*(u[k,j+1] + u[k,j-1]) + (1 - 2*s)*u[k,j]
    return u
u_num = DiffusionSolver(x,t,s,L,InitCond,LeftEnd,RightEnd)
u_num = u_num.T #HERE!
plt.plot(x, u_num)
plt.show()
```

This works for me.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.
in the case the plot will basically show all the time steps from 0 to tmax, not only at t = tmax right ?

Comment: What is T in this case ?

Comment: T is the numpy method of Transforming a "Matrix". Therefore (x,y) -> (y,x)

Comment: The rest of your code functions however you intended (I only bug checked the bit you were having a problem with). I can only assume that means that the entire graph will plot. It certainly looked like it when I ran the code.